# MsgBox loop for each row using Excel Visual Basic

Tags: vba, excel, foreach, msgbox

This is the first time working with VBA with Excel. I am practicing using formulas and displaying the values by using both the Excel cells and MsgBoxes.

My current issue is most likely a simple fix but have yet to figure it out.

**I want to make my MsgBox show the following after each line is populated:**

MSG popup

```
Socks Gross Sale is 56.37
```

MSG popup

```
Lotion Gross Sale is 59.12
..etc
```

However, when I first try to run my commented out code line `MsgBox Range("A14:A21").Value & " Gross Sale is " & Range("F14:F21").Value` it gives an error `Run-time error '13': Type mismatch` so it doesn't work.

Therefore, so far I am working with my code line `MsgBox Range("A14:A21").Value & " Gross Sale is " & Range("F14:F21").Value`
 which only populates the Sock line continuously through the loop. Any suggestions ?

```
For Each Cell In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B14:E21").Cells

   Range("F14:F21").Formula = "=SUM((B14*D14)-((B14*D14)*E14))"
  'MsgBox Range("A14:A21").Value & " Gross Sale is " & Range("F14:F21").Value

  'Gives me first line only and makes pop up show twice as many times as (all)total rows
  MsgBox Range("A14").Value & " Gross Sale is " & Range("F14").Value

Next
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send a range to Msgbox .. it's looking for a string .. you need to build the string each time ...  I recommend something like this:

```
For i = 14 To 21

    MsgBox Range("a" & i).Value & " Gross Sale is " & Range("F" & i).Value

Next i
```

That'll loop through the ROWS (aka Lines) you want ... and splice the cells together where you want to pull the values from ...

```
For Each Cell
```

loops through each Cell ... not line ..

Comment: this is really close to how I was hoping to do it (short and simple) This worked smoothly! I really appreciate it. I guess a separate loop is the best way to go.

Comment: Yeah, that's the basics, obviously the hardcoded "14" and "21" you'll have to play with if you want / need a more dynamic range ;)

Comment: Exactly. Slowly but surely I hope to get this new coding language down. Just learned yesterday that Excel used VBA O.o . Thanks again! I've got to keep practicing

Comment: Another sneaky way of doing things, like Iturner hinted at in his solution: if you Name a range, say Cells A14:A21 (note, just 1 col), you can then use the `For each Cell` and use that named range. In that manner, you get the proper number of iterations .. and you can use the cells A14:A21 as your base (hint: think `OFFSET` function among other things ;) )   Good luck!

Comment: I will definitely check into more versions :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use arrays to hold the values from your worksheet, and then loop through each element of both arrays, using their index in each iteration to produce the message you are after.

```
Sub produceMsg()
    Dim i As Byte
    Dim arrProductName As Variant
    Dim arrGrossSale As Variant
    arrGrossSale = Range("F2:F9").Value
    arrProductName = Range("A2:A9").Value

    For i = 1 To UBound(arrGrossSale, 1)
        MsgBox (arrProductName(i, 1) & " Gross sale is " & arrGrossSale(i, 1))
    Next i
End Sub
```

When populating arrays from a worksheet, you always produce a 2 dimensional array, regardless of if you're only providing 1 dimension to the array. That is why we have to specify the 2nd dimension as being '1' when looping through the array. Hope this helps.

Comment: This works really well too. I only chose @Ditto because his was more simplistic however I do like the name declares for each range. I didn't think of that way so I am happy you showed me this! If only I can "checkmark" 2 answers

Answer (score 0):

On a side note I made the following update to show two decimal places on MsgBox:

```
MsgBox Range("a" & i).Value & " Gross Sale is $" & FormatNumber(Round(Range("F" & i).Value, 2), 2)
```

I added `FormatNumber` because when I use `Round` it removes any number whose second decimal place is a `0`. With `FormatNumber` it keeps the `0`

Addition to @Ditto